# Shoulder discomfort

Tags: bodybuilding, pain, shoulders, joints, shoulder-cuff

When I'm doing incline curls with my elbows behind my body, or lat pulldowns and I'm at the very top of the movement, or when I'm doing cable chest flies, I feel a discomfort or irritation throughout my shoulder. Any idea what the reason is?

Comment: This question seems like it would be more appropriate for a doctor or physical therapist.

Comment: Sounds like your biceps long head is giving you some issue. Like thomas said, better to seek help from a healthcare professional to get accurate assessments and diagnosis